# Fill Remaining Height backward compatible

Tags: css

I am trying to make my div fill the remaining height.  I have managed to do so in the following way:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.my-container{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a js fiddle I made to demonstrate my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/w1k3po37/1/

My question is, I feel that I am kind of hacking the default behavior with the overflow and I was wondering if the way I have done this is correct and if there is a better way or if there are any consequences I should be watching out for because of the way I have done this?  Keep in mind I need to ensure this still works with IE8.  So things like calc I cannot use.

EDIT:

After working with this for a bit, my limitation is that if the height is more than 100%, the page will not scroll.  Does anyone know of a way I can accomplish this without using tables or display: tables properties?

Answer (score 0):

Easy to use with absolute positioning.

```css
.container {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background-color: #ccf;}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

This works even in IE 6!

Comment: Absolute will take it out of the normal flow of the page, i fear that will get a lot messier to work with than an overflow.  I tried updating my fiddle with your example and the results are not quite nice.  https://jsfiddle.net/w1k3po37/2/

Comment: You need to be careful when you are working with absolute. What exactly you wanna achieve?

Comment: Basically what I have shown with my first fiddle in my question, I was just mostly wondering if the way I have accomplished is right or wrong.  If there is a better way I should be doing it.